# How to vertically combine two pandas dataframes that have different number of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There are two dataframes, one dataframe might have less columns than another one. For instance,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'B'],
    'col2': [2, 9],
    'col3': [0, 1]
})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['G'],
    'col2': [3]
})
```

The `df` and `df1` are shown as follows.

[image]

I would like to combine these two dataframes together, and the missing values should be assigned as some given value, like -100. How to perform this kind of combination.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True).fillna(-100)
print (df)
  col1  col2   col3
0    A     2    0.0
1    B     9    1.0
2    G     3 -100.0
```

If need same dtypes add [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
d = df.dtypes.append(df1.dtypes).to_dict()
df = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True).fillna(-100).astype(d)
print (df)

  col1  col2  col3
0    A     2     0
1    B     9     1
2    G     3  -100
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `reindex` the DataFrames first to "preserve" the dtypes; then concatenate:

```py
cols = df.columns.union(df1.columns)
out = pd.concat([d.reindex(columns=cols, fill_value=-100) for d in [df, df1]], 
                ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```py
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     2     0
1    B     9     1
2    G     3  -100
```

Comment: Why not concat and fill after, instead of the loop

Comment: @sammywemmy I thought of that but (i) jezrael already had it before I did (ii) figured float columns might not be desirable